# How can I pass data from MySQL to Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi i know some basic sql stuff but not so good in oracle.

I have my data from MYSQL database and I have a remote Oracle DB which I don't have rights to.

Question 1st :How do I pass the value of "RLI" from mySQL db to Oracle DB.
 2nd: How to insert it to the the query below(specifically the last line). 3rd: Alternatives or suggestions.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT 
        ci.catalog_item_name AS catalog_item,lnop.value AS os_type 
    FROM
        UCS_USER.ln_options_at_readytosignoff lnop,UCS_USER.reservationlineitems rli,UCS_USER.order_item oi,UCS_USER.catalog_item ci
    WHERE 
        lnop.quote_ln_id=rli.quote_ln_id
        and rli.order_item_id=oi.order_item_id
        and oi.catalog_item_id = ci.catalog_item_id
        and lnop.option_name like '%Type%'
        and rli.ln_type=1
        and rli.reservation_ln_id in(select a.reservation_ln_id from UCS_USER.reservationlineitems a
        left join UCS_USER.reservationlineitems b on a.reservation_ln_id = b.depends_on
        where (a.reservation_ln_id = (:rli1_bv) or  b.reservation_ln_id =(:rli2_bv)) ");
```

I need to change the bold values that is from MYSQL db.

where (a.reservation_ln_id = (**:rli1_bv**) or  b.reservation_ln_id =(**:rli2_bv**)) ");
does oci_bind work?

```
        $rli1=  $data_from_sql;
        $rli2=  $data_from_sql;
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":rli1_bv", $rli1);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":rli2_bv", $rli2);
```

Comment: DB2 is an IBM database.

Comment: What do you mean by an IBM database? I don't have any rights in that Oracle db just view so I can't change the settings to let Oracle listen to MySQL. So is it possible to pass the data in a variable in oracle then oracle reads it to perform the query?